# Unable to kill javaw process on Win Server (without hard reboot)

Tags: java, virtual-machine, vmware, windows-server-2008-r2

The problem is in the subj. Javaw refuses to die. Tried: TM killing a process, TM killing a tree, kill.exe PID, taskkill - all fail. 
Blocks soft reboot. The only solution so far has been a hard kill (power down).

Any ideas how to deal with this? Especially if you're running a VM which you can't easily bounce from the VmWare console (due to limited access).

Running McAfee on that box. No malware found.

Comment: There are maybe 3 ways this might happen: #1 You don't have permission (it is owned by another user and you aren't admin), #2: It is waiting on a device or file system: Say it does a large read from a really slow network, #3: It is being controlled by a debugger.

Comment: Oh ... if something is holding a handle open on the process, you can kill the process but I think it will still show up in task manager.

Comment: I'm an admin, so it's not #1; for #2 - process uses local files, however, I wonder if McAffee may be holding it somehow; and for #4 - I can't really kill it, the GUI window still shows up and then prevents the reboot subsequently. I'll see if I can find something else.

Comment: If you have an answer for your question, you should mark it as accepted. Editing the title to include "Solved" is not necessary on StackOverflow.

Comment: Oh, I answered it myself, so I don't know whether I should have "accepted" my own self for this.

Answer (score 2):

Answer(s): 2 of them, as a matter of fact.

1) The culprit that was freezing java processes turned out (as commonly found) the broken McAffee system. Turning it off completely substantially eased the pain.

2) Killing the javaw stuck process eventually was achieved with maximum efficiency as:

```
taskkill /pid $pid /t /f
```

Hope this helps if you ever encounter it.